# How to locate an app to share to in iOS13 share sheet via UI test?

Tags: ios, ios13, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest, uitest

I am using a UI test to check sharing a file to a target app. For that, I am using [multi-app UI testing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/409?time=494) as follows:

- the target app should become active when sharing a given file to it
- a helper app `UITestsHelper`is a simple document-based app template
  that installs a file in its container, navigates to it and shares the
  file with the target app

The problem is that, when the share sheet is opened, there is no meaningful text that I can use to find the cell to share the file to the target app, in this case shown as "MyApp".

[image]

When inspecting the UI hierarchy in the logs, this is the relevant section:

```
ScrollView, {{0.0, 617.0}, {414.0, 132.0}}
  Cell, {{13.0, 617.0}, {78.0, 118.5}}, label: 'AirDrop'
  Cell, {{106.5, 617.0}, {78.0, 118.5}}, label: 'Nachrichten'
  Cell, {{200.0, 617.0}, {78.0, 118.5}}, label: 'Mail'
  Cell, {{293.5, 617.0}, {78.0, 131.5}}, label: 'Aktivität'
  Cell, {{387.0, 617.0}, {78.0, 131.5}}, label: 'Aktivität'
```

As you can see, system apps and services, such as AirDrop, Messages and Mail have a meaningful label (here in German because that's the system language). Third party apps just show with label "Activity" (Aktivität in German).

I am blindly tapping on the fourth cell right now, as a way to choose the first non-system app, but I find this extremely fragile.

Is there a more reliable way to share a a file to a target app?

Comment: Can you check for the `staticText` or the `image` instead ?

Comment: There are no further descriptors for the app cell @cesarmarch, I copied the relevant section of the view hierarchy as seen by the UI test runner.

Answer (score 0):

I also have found this bug. I workaround it in the next way – I find all this "Activity" cells (`app.cells.matching(identifier: "Activity").allElementsBoundByIndex`) and tap them one after the other until the needed is found (I check it by looking at target app `.state`)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to deal with the wrong app then? Like in the example from the question, if you tap on "Messages", then Messages will open, which wasn't the intended destination. What do you do in that case?